# Chaining method calls in Expression Tree at runtime

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I am looking to build an expression tree dynamically at runtime.  The expression will call several methods and pass the result of one method to the next with the last method returning something.  I can build and run single method call expressions without difficulty but cannot figure out how to chain these methods together in an Expression.

Simplified code below.  The live code has methods with variable number of method calls and params.

Conceptually  I'm trying to get the equivalent to this at runtime by combining expression1 & expression2

```
var uncompileable = HostNumber.GetHostNumber("Bleacher").HostStatus.GetHostStatus(); // Status = "Online"
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace SO
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConstantExpression param1 = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType("Bleacher", typeof(String)));      
            MethodCallExpression expression1 = Expression.Call(typeof(HostNumber), "GetHostNumber", null, new Expression[] { param1 });

            ConstantExpression param2 = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType("45", typeof(int)));
            MethodCallExpression expression2 = Expression.Call(typeof(HostStatus), "GetHostStatus", null, new Expression[] { param2 });

            var invokee = Expression.Lambda(expression1).Compile();
            var result = invokee.DynamicInvoke();

        }
    }

    public class HostNumber
    {
        public static int GetHostNumber(string hostName)
        {
            return 45;
        }
    }

    public static class HostStatus
    {
        public static string GetHostStatus(int hostNumber)
        {
            return "Online";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `HostNumber.GetHostNumber("Bleacher").HostStatus.GetHostStatus()` does not compile becuase `GetHostNumber` return an integer, not some object that has a `HostStatus` property.

Comment: I know.  I just added that line to show the concept of what I am trying to achive.  The output of HostNumber.GetHostNumber("Bleacher") (45) should be then passed to HostStatus.GetHostStatus(). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you would do it:

```
var expression =
    Expression.Call(
        typeof (HostStatus).GetMethod("GetHostStatus", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static),
        Expression.Call(
            typeof (HostNumber).GetMethod("GetHostNumber", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static),
            Expression.Constant("Bleacher", typeof (string))));

var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(expression).Compile();

var result = func();
```

By the way, it is not clear to me why are you doing this. Why are you building a static expression and then compile it?

Comment: That works thanks. These method calls are parsed from a configuration file (DSL).

Comment: You welcome. I see. So its dynamic because the method names are not static.

Comment: Yes exactly but the expression might contain one method call or up to three and the method calls might have no parameters or up to two. So your code might get complicated.   I had tried to use expression visitor to merge the expressions together but got lost along the way.

Comment: Take a look at [LINQKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), it might help you with what you are trying to do. It allows you to use one expression in another and then expand the result to create a real combined expression. I am not sure if it applies to your case though.